# _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke “update” command: application has been destroyed error on pyplot.pause()

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter, video-processing

I'm working on serial data from arduino and processing the data in python using opencv2 and matplotlib library. Everything just works fine but everytime I close the figure window I got the error while I dont even use tkinter library.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\project\coba.py", line 57, in <module>
    plt.pause(0.2)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 438, in pause
    canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2407, in start_event_loop
    self.flush_events()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 390, in flush_events
    self._master.update()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1305, in update
    self.tk.call('update')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed
```

I dont even declare tkinter library,

```
import cv2
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

the use of matplotlib here is to show video from camera and serial data output side by side in realtime and the app is supposed to close when I press 'q'.

```
#create two subplots
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

#create two image plots
im1 = ax1.imshow(grab_frame(video))
im2 = plt.imshow(cap2)
while True:
        #read from serial
        buffer = port.readline()
        temper = buffer.decode('utf-8')
        temper = temper.reshape(8,8)
        
        #update data
        im1.set_data(grab_frame(video))
        im2.set_data(temper)
        plt.pause(0.2)

        #stopper
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if(key == ord('q')):
                break

plt.show()
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

should I use tkinter library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried some ways to get over it and still i dont get where this has been done with **tkinter**, But IMO it's about I can't close the program when it is paused. So, instead of I put the stopper at bottom, I put it above the `plt.pause()`. this gonna looks something like this:

```
#update data

im1.set_data(grab_frame(video))
im2.set_data(temper)
#stopper
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if(key == ord('q')):
        break
plt.pause(0.2)
```